# Why is my view rotating 90 degrees prior to it scaling?

Tags: ios

I have a UIView which I want to automatically zoom to be the size of the screen when the user clicks on it.

I took code from http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/09/zoomingviewcontroller-to-animate-uiview.html

and the zooming works, except just before the zoom begins the view rotates 90 degrees. Why is that happening?

(The view is within a carousel. Prior to the user tapping the view, the device is rotated into landscape, at which point the view controller for the carousel is pushed onto the navigation stack and the carousel displayed.)

The code is:

```
- (void)buttonTapped:(UIButton *) sender
{
    NSInteger index = [self.carousel indexOfItemView:sender];

    UIView *currentView = [self.carousel itemViewAtIndex: index];
    UIView *proxyView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:currentView.frame];
    proxyView.hidden = YES;
    proxyView.autoresizingMask = currentView.autoresizingMask;
    [currentView.superview addSubview: proxyView];

    CGRect frame = [currentView.window convertRect:currentView.frame fromView:proxyView.superview];
    [currentView.window addSubview:currentView];
    currentView.frame = frame;

    [UIView
     animateWithDuration:2.4
     animations:^{
         currentView.frame = currentView.window.bounds;
     }];
```

(carousel is a UIView derived object, from https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that the problem is either:

```
currentView.frame = frame;
```

or:

```
currentView.frame = currentView.window.bounds;
```

In landscape mode, your view or one of the enclosing views has a transform that rotates everything 90°. As the [UIView docs indicate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/frame), the `frame` property is undefined if the view's `transform` property is anything other than the identity transform. It may be that setting your view's `frame` implicitly sets its `transform` back to the identity, which causes it to rotate back to portrait orientation.

The docs at the linked above both warn against changing `frame` when there's a transform, and provide a solution:

> Changes to this property can be animated. However, if the transform
>   property contains a non-identity transform, the value of the frame
>   property is undefined and should not be modified. In that case, you
>   can reposition the view using the center property and adjust the size
>   using the bounds property instead.

Comment: If I comment out the first line, the view jumps to the bottom left hand corner (it was in the center) and then rotates. If I comment out the second line it stays centered but still rotates (but doesn't zoom of course).

Comment: @ChrisP.Bacon The solution, as explained in the docs, is to animate `bounds` and `center` instead of `frame` if there's a non-identity transform.

Comment: The rotation happens before the animi nation, so if I comment out the animation code entirely then the rotation still happens.

Comment: Sorry -- I mis-spoke: The solution is to *change* `bounds` and `center` instead of `frame` if there's a non-identity transform. **Stop setting `frame`. Set `bounds` instead.**